# Global menu support in SmartGit 17

Tags: 16.04, hud

SmartGit 17 **by design** has built-in menu (SmartGit 8 hasn't).

[image]

I want new SmartGit to look the same as its previous version (with global menu usage).
Is there any workaround?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks, it's much clearer now. Looking at the [official download page](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download), SmartGit 17 RC is pre-release software. Bugs in pre-release software are kind of off topic here. Instead you should report the bug to the maintainers or developers.

Comment: I did. Support said that “The menu bar embedded into the SmartGit window is intentional...” (you can read full respond using link in answer). This question could help somebody, probably this change will be in next release.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's fine then. Could you please clarify in your question that this behaviour is "by design" and your question is a workaround for the intended behaviour? People like me may become confused about the premise otherwise. Ping me if you want an up-vote on the result. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follwing [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/smartgit/yNtHxVXE0r8/m_X__Z8HEQAJ) answer, it is necessary to

1. edit file `$SMARTGIT_HOME$/bin/smartgit.sh`,
2. comment this line: `export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`

No built-in menu anymore:

[image: SmartGit: no built in menu]